# Nested for loops to calculate max. temperature from a csv

Tags: numpy, nested-loops, cumsum

I'm starting a class on advanced data structures and I'm struggling to answer the problems shown in the image below.The NYC_temperature.csv has hourly temperatures and you have to calculate it by day to then show what was the warmest 30-day period

[image: The Problems I have to solve]

Comment: That's nice. You've not asked a question, here.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just wanted some help to solve the exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(data)-24*30-1):
    temp = 0
    for j in range(i, i+30):
        temp += data[j]
    maxtemp = max(temp, maxtemp)
```